# Symfony dependency injection - How to inject a service in an option array

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

For this example i have to simple classes demonstrating the dependency on A from B

```
class A{

}

class B{

    public function __construct(A $a ){

    }
}
```

Using Symfony to create some service definitions and setting up the DI

```
test.Service.A:
    class: A

test.Service.B:
    class: B
    arguments: ["@test.Service.A"]
```

This is working as expected.

Now there is some third class which does not explicitly define its depenedencies via constructor args rather with an plain old **options array**

```
class C{

    private $b;

    public function __construct( array $options = array() ){
        if( isset($options['B']) && $options['B'] instanceof B){
            $this->b = $options['B'];
        }
    }
}
```

Creating this object would look something like this

```
$c = new C( array(
    'B' => new B( new A() )
));
```

Now i want to create a service definiton for C in yml

```
parameters:
    test.options.C:
        B: test.Service.B

test.Service.C:
    class: C
    arguments: ["%test.options.C%"]
```

How can i make **test.options.C.B** pointing to my service **test.Service.B** ?

Does it work this way ?

```
parameters:
    test.options.C:
        B: "@test.Service.B"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it does not work this way, `parameters` know nothing about services.

A solution for you might be creating a `Factory` service:

```
services:
    test.Service.C:
        class: C
        factory: ['@factory.service', createC]

    factory.service:
        class: D
        arguments: ["@test.Service.B"]
```

And your `D` class:

```
class D
{
    public function __construct(B $bInstance)
    {
        $this->B = $bInstance;
    }

    public static function createC()
    {
        return new C(array('B' => $this->B));
    }
}
```

Check the [doc](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html) for more info how to use factories to create service

Answer (score 1):

There're three types of injections with DependencyInjection Component. Usually, you'll use just injections in the constructor because this way the DI Component can be sure, you're passing correct classes.

See: https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html

I don't think it's possible to make DI to pass an array of dependencies (I don't even think there's any advantage over listing them in the constructor) so the best option might be using [setter injections](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/injection_types.html#setter-injection) instead.

You can also use a factory to create services, see https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/factories.html.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Expression language for inject the service defined as parameters as follow:

```
parameters:
    test.options.C:
        B: "test.Service.B"

services:
    test.Service.A:
        class: A

    test.Service.B:
        class: B
        arguments: ["@test.Service.A"]

    test.Service.C:
        class: C
        arguments: ["@=service(parameter('test.options.C'))"]
```

More info in the doc about  [How to Inject Values Based on Complex Expressions](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/expression_language.html)